# D3 bar chart add legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, legend

I have made a bar chart in d3 but I am struggeling with 2 things. 
First of all I want to add a legend because I have 2 different bars so I want people to know what each bar is.

The second I want to load data from a json file instead of this:

```
var data = [
  {
    "year":1970,
    "count1":1,
    "count2":0
  },
  {
    "year":1975,
    "count1":1,
    "count2":0
  },
  {
    "year":1980,
    "count1":1,
    "count2":1
  }]
```

But when I try to use a json file my map function gives an error.

My code :

```
var svgSelect = d3.select("svg")
var width = 1020
var height = 900
var margin = {top: 35, right: 25, bottom: 35, left: 50}
var paddingBars = .2
var axisTicks = {amount: 25, outerSize: 0}

var svg = svgSelect
    .append("svg")
    .attr("widht", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`)

var xScale0 = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]).padding(paddingBars)
var xScale1 = d3.scaleBand()
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale0).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize)
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(axisTicks.amount).tickSizeOuter(axisTicks.outerSize)

xScale0.domain(data.map(d => d.year))
xScale1.domain(['count1', 'count2']).range([0, xScale0.bandwidth()])
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.count1 > d.count2 ? d.count1 : d.count2)])

var year = svg.selectAll(".year")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "year")
  .attr("transform", d => `translate(${xScale0(d.year)},0)`)

/* Add count1 bars */
year.selectAll(".bar.count1")
  .data(d => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar count1")
.style("fill","blue")
  .attr("x", d => xScale1('count1'))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.count1))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => {
    return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.count1)
  })

/* Add coun2 bars */
year.selectAll(".bar.count2")
  .data(d => [d])
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar count2")
.style("fill","red")
  .attr("x", d => xScale1('count2'))
  .attr("y", d => yScale(d.count2))
  .attr("width", xScale1.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", d => {
    return height - margin.top - margin.bottom - yScale(d.count2)
  })

// Add the X Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "x axis")
   .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.top - margin.bottom})`)
   .call(xAxis);

// Add the Y Axis
svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)
```

Comment: Your code does not contain an attempt at adding a legend. There are infinite ways to add legend to a chart. How do you plan yours to be?

Comment: I don't see any d3 json loading, be aware v4 and v5 use different methods